# Atom Pakage Install error: binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path)

Tags: atom-editor

[image]

I am on windows 8.1 and I have installed Atom x64. When I try to install any package, I get the error as shown in the screenshot attached for your reference. I researched the internet but could not find any solution to this problem. As this problem has not been reported before on this portal therefore I created this question to also help others who might face this issue in future.

Comment: Which atom's version you are using?
Can you post the output of `atom --version`?

Comment: I am using Atom 1.31.2 x64 version.

Comment: have you tried my answer below?

Comment: Yes I tried that and after that I am getting this new error:  `spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT`

Comment: Could you check if `C:\Windows\System32` is in your system's `PATH` environment variable, and if it's not there, add it? This error looks like it's caused by not finding cmd.exe in the `system's PATH` directories, and apparently, the `System32` directory can disappear for a number of reasons.

Comment: I tried adding `C:\Windows\System32` to PATH variable. Still getting same error by restarting Atom afterwards.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/aWvsqwpDdU9m

Comment: And this: https://www.screencast.com/t/dFPv9G6WwG3

Comment: Can you take a look at `COMSPEC` variable?

Comment: `CompSpec` is set to be `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;`. Is it correct? I have no idea.

Comment: yup, also put me the screenshot for variables, please!

Comment: Here is the screenshot of environment variables: https://www.screencast.com/t/doKQp330cnYF

Comment: Place this path at the very beginning of `PATH`, please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman I tried and even restarted my PC. Still getting the same error.

Comment: One more thing You can try, Upgrade to the Atom `v1.32.0`, this is the latest and hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: You can grab it from here: https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.32.0/AtomSetup-x64.exe

Comment: But before that completely uninstall the existing version.

Comment: I uninstalled the existing Atom installation from Add or Remove Programs first and then reinstalled Atom from the link you mentioned. Still, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message stated that there's an issue with the path for `TEMP`.

So you resolve this issue as:

> Go into **system paths** and reset **TMP** and **TEMP** to
>   **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp** or change it to an entirely different
>   path.

Also, Atom has released a new version with various fixes and it's `v1.32.0`

You can download it from the link below:

https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.32.0/AtomSetup-x64.exe

Comment: The TMP and TEMP are the same as you mentioned.

Comment: I uninstalled the existing Atom installation from Add or Remove Programs first and then reinstalled Atom from the link you mentioned. Still, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Atom assumes you have one folder specified in the TEMP environment variables. From your screenshot it appears you have 2 or more (separated by semi-colons). Set it to a single Temp folder (probably the first one), and retry.

Some applications treat the %TEMP% like %PATH% where there are multiple values.

You could raise an issue with Atom to use the first item in the list, or similar.

Comment: I tried to remove multiple paths in TEMP and now the error has changed. It is now giving error: `spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT`.